# About the definition of **independent points of infinite order** in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(G,+)$ be a group.

I am asking about the definition of **independent points of infinite order** in $G$. A search in google does not give helpful information.

Comment: No wonder you didn't find anything googling: this seems to be a non-standard definition. Where did you get it from? Perhaps you meant "$\,\Bbb Z-$linearly independent *elements* in an abelian group", or something of the like? Or free-torsion generators or stuff?

Comment: No, this is comes from **Rational points of infinite order on elliptic curves** where $G$ is the set of rational solutions. See this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve

Comment: Oh, dear: this is a very different thing! You should make sure you include all relevant information in your questions. People can't usually guess.

Comment: Actually, googling *independent points of infinite order* leads you immediately to the Wikipedia article on elliptic curves.

Comment: Interesting though the OP said there was no helpful information after googling...

Comment: @ DonAntonio: Yes, since I am looking on the wrong side, i.e., the definition for groups!. Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably reading about [elliptic curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve).

An abelian group $G$ is the same thing as a $\mathbf{Z}$-module. So the definition is a partial analogue to that in vector spaces. Elements $g_{1}, \dots, g_{n} \in G$ are said to be (linearly) independent if
$$
a_{1} g_{1} + \dots + a_{n} g_{n} = 0,
$$
for $a_{i} \in \mathbf{Z}$ implies $a_{i} = 0$ for all $i$.

If $g_{1}, \dots, g_{n}$ are independent, then each of them has infinite order. (If, by way of contradiction, $g_{1}$, say has order $a > 0$, then $a g_{1} + 0 g_{2} + \dots + 0 g_{n} = 0$.)

The cardinality of a maximal independent set in $G$ is its [rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_an_abelian_group).

Comment: @ Andreas Caranti: Thank you very much for clarification.

Comment: @Chaos, you're welcome.